# Selenium is not working any more with GitHub Actions

Tags: python, github, selenium-webdriver, github-actions

I created an alternative planning for my university using Selenium. It all worked for a year and a half, but for the past two days, this seems to not be working any more. The workflow that runs the web scraping for my application returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/work/NovaPlanning/NovaPlanning/scraping/scraper.py", line 109, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.18/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 67, in __init__
    super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.18/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 205, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.18/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 289, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.18/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 344, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.18/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 1
```

Here is where I instantiate the webdriver:

```python
options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://hplanning2023.umons.ac.be/invite")
```

I tried switching to Chrome instead of Firefox and removing the optional parameter "options".

Comment: Please do not use `[solved]` in your question title. Instead, [post an answer yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) *and* [mark that as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). An accepted answer will have more visibility and will be more likely to help others like you who got stumped by this problem.

Comment: ["EDIT" does not belong](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131009/what-should-i-keep-out-of-my-posts-and-titles/131011#131011) in any post (that is what the revision history is for). The question should be as if it was written right now.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it be replacing `options.headless = True` by `options.add_argument("-headless")`